# Detect whether the OS architecture is x86, x64 or arm64 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to display the correct download option for an application so I need to detect the OS architecture.

Is there any way to detect that? Assuming Windows 7 or newer versions of Windows, ignoring other OS's.

It doesn't need to be so reliable, as I'm going to make it easy to select the correct version manually.

I've found a few UserAgent strings online (for x86 and x64), but I didn't find any arm64 examples, so I'm not sure if it's possible to use that.

Comment: This should help [ua-parser](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js)